# The "WireUpCoreRuntime" task failed unexpectedly Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing UWP application for remote device using VS17. I suddenly got this message

```
Error       The "WireUpCoreRuntime" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.Build.Net.CoreRuntimeTask.WireUpCoreRuntime.InternalExecute()
   at Microsoft.Build.Net.CoreRuntimeTask.WireUpCoreRuntime.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() DataManagementApp
```

And I am stuck at this error for about week. I dont know what cause it. Last thing that I made was that I move GPIO routines to external library. After that, each build ends with this message.

What I tried:

- Turn off antivirus

  - Redo last update (library is working on other similar solutions)
  - Redo several last changes in build
  - update VS, repair VS and repair SDKs
  - update versions of libraries
  - reboot target device
  - build project on other PC (with fresh VS), copy code on brand new project and 
    run it on my or other PC
  - get rid of anything that using Linq library in code.
  - Run VS as administrator

With no success at all. I will be very happy if anyone will help me with solving this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I messed up with appxmanifest file. I use AppServices for background work. In [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) they have got some changes in appxmanifest file, but they suddenly throws error.

```
    <Application Id="AppServicesProvider.App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="AppServicesProvider.App">
```

Have to be simplified into

```
<Application Id="App">
```

And it throws no error anymore.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same error renaming the `Assembly name` for a UWP application.

I discovered you also need to open `Package.appxmanifest` and change the `Entry point` to the same value you used in `Assembly name`.